# Creating running total chart

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts

I want to create a chart in Google Sheets with cumulative Profit (H) column but without creating the second column (I). Are there any solutions?

[image]

Comment: A strange desire is a dubious decision.

Answer (score 2):

```
=SPARKLINE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H; 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(H2:H)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(H2:H)))*H2:H); 
 SIGN(H2:H)^2); IFERROR(1/0))); 
 {"charttype" \ "line"; 
  "color" \ "red"; 
  "linewidth" \ 3})
```

[image]

```
=SPARKLINE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H; 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(H2:H)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(H2:H)))*H2:H); 
 SIGN(H2:H)^2); IFERROR(1/0))); 
 {"charttype" \ "column"; 
  "color" \ "red"})
```

[image]

Comment: This solution maybe works but it not a chart object. For example I can't see chart's legend or publish this chart.

Comment: @VadimSelyakov this is all you can get without column I

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, except I need to filter the range by a specific date. I've been using **FILTER(Log!$N$2:$N, Log!$B$2:$B=A3)**, where A3 is the cell containing a date to filter by. I can't find the correct way to alter your solution to include a filtered range. Could you please enlighten me!? Thanks

Comment: @MustImpress can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 Thanks for the quick reply! Here's a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGkyzc_1KlGvrj2Ug_0KB1Z2NnPKvvITfOFBxGTj96U/edit?usp=sharing

The chart is on the "Days" tab. "Log" is just input data. I've managed to reduce the rows using a filter but I can't see how to apply a filter to your clever logic. It's beyond me :)

Comment: @MustImpress sheet is private

Comment: Damn, sorry... *edited* 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGkyzc_1KlGvrj2Ug_0KB1Z2NnPKvvITfOFBxGTj96U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MustImpress here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AyGvaKZ2frWDXh-T2VhBJPHSccgTB006A7TJ-zgSERs/edit#gid=693274880

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! Thank you so much!!